# reactjs websocket in a browser client: use the socket connection inside an effect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, websocket, ws

I have a reactjs client that connects to a websocket server, however when I try to initialize it outside of an effect hook, the websocket object is undefined, but it initializes when its in an effect hook

like so:

```
effect(()=>{
  connection = new WebSocket(url)
  //do some stuff
})
```

the issue is that I want to send things based on an event that happens in the reactjs app

```
effect(()=>{
  connection.send(messages)
},[messages])
```

at that point, connection is undefined, despite the connection being made then, I can only assume that since I have to use the Native WS for browsers, I have to initialize the websocket elsewhere, but I don't know where

Answer (score 1):

Maintain state variable for connection. Create only one time and have close connection in effect. (Empty dependency array to run once)

```
const [connection, setConnection] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  connection = new WebSocket(url);
  setConnection(connection);
  return () => connection.close()
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  connection.send(messages)
}, [messages])
```